# Multiple Single Page Application or a Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, single-page-application, hateoas

I'm writing a (almost) "wizard" web-based project. The base architecture is an Restful service consumed by a web-client that aim to follow the HATOAS approach.
Since is a not so lightweight project I'm was thinking of splitting the project in three different SinglePageApplications.
For you guys it's a good idea? If so which is the best approach for passing the parameters among the pages?
Eg. One page manage a "resource A", you do some basic CRUD operation, then select one of them for the next step: eg. analisys based on object related to "resource A", so you should to pass at least the "resource A" id and maybe some other parameters.
Thanks,
f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar project, had to write "Contract Manegement System" for mobile network company, I had login page for 3 type of users - "Admin" , "Manager", "Resposible Person", there were 3 page for these type of users, each of these page represent Single Page Application, that used REST services for interaction with server, and pure JavaScript for passing data into HTML elements, it worked very quickly like desktop application...

Comment: thanks Taron, could you please give me some tips about a good approach in order to pass parameters between two SPA? :-)

Comment: I mean suppose that i need to select a "product A" from a SPA and pass the Id to a second SPA. Do you think that maybe it's a good thing to pass the parameter in this way: www.example.org/spa_2.x?resourceA=75123 and then use this url as a base for the SPA. But what about the reading of that parameters? I have to read them server-side and then pass them in javascript or it's better to read and parse url via js?

Comment: Yes, it would be better to make logic so that it is not tied to the query sting. Send product_ID to the server from one SPA and get it from another SPA